# How to build a good benchmark class for parameters methods

Tags: c#, performance, benchmarking

i have read about my question a lot.
and i saw many ways to write that class.
but how can i create one who check methods with parameters.
or maybe my methodology is wrong ?
and do this in a test class ?
Thank in advance 
G.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DI frameworks and add interceptors. [Here](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/interceptors.html) is for castle.